# Are two different classes’ fighting styles two different class features?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, multi-classing

The fighting style feature states that

> You can’t take a Fighting Style option more than once, even if you later get to choose again.

However, if you are a Ranger 2/Fighter 1 (for example), can you choose the same fighting style as a Ranger and as a Fighter because it’s two different class features?

Answer (score 6):

As you quoted, you **can't take the same option twice**.

You can take two different options as a Ranger 2 / Fighter 1, like say, Archery, and Two-Weapon Fighting. But you can't have Archery twice.